# jQuery Animate not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, animation

For some reason when I click the close icon it animated the position down like expected but then automatically comes back up.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/fq7na1zr/

If you go to the fiddle and click the orange box, it will animate its position up and also show you a X to close it.

When you click the X it animates the div down again but then it shoots back up.

How do I get the div to stay down?

HTML:

```
    <div data-position="down" id="container">
        <div id="close" style="display: none;">X</div>
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('#container').click(function() {
            var currentState = $(this).data('position');

            if (currentState == "down") {
                $('#container').animate({bottom: "20%"});
                $('#container').attr('data-position','up');
                $('#close').css('display','block');
            }

        });

        $('#close').click(function() {
            $('#container').animate({bottom: "-100%"});
            $('#container').attr('data-position','down');
            $('#close').css('display','none');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because while you click on the X, the container click event also gets triggered because the click goes through, so you get whatever happens on the "X" click event first, and then whatever happens in the .container click event, which is, as expected, to go back up. You should make some flag like "isDown" and set it to true or false when relevant, and make an if condition with it inside each event handler in order to avoid both actions to take place.

Comment: There is an if statement there to see if down is set in the data-position. That should be returning false, correct?

Answer (score 0):

No need to over-complicate it with JavaScript. Just toggle CSS classes:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="close">X</div>
  lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#container.up {
  bottom: 20%;
}

#container.down {
  bottom: -100%;
}

#container.up #close {
  display: block;
}

#close {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var $container = $('#container')
var $close = $('#close')

$container.click(() => $container.addClass('up'))
$close.click(() => $container.addClass('down'))
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fq7na1zr/3/**

Comment: How XBrowser friends is this method?

Comment: @JamesG highly supported if using regular functions https://jsfiddle.net/fq7na1zr/4/ https://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Answer (score 0):

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

will solve your problem. Because you click on the #close div and the #container div too. With event.stopPropagation(); you prevent calling the event listener for the #container div.

Comment: Where would I put this in the above code. I put it just inside the #close click event and it worked however when I click the div it still jumps up a little. When I click the div I need nothing to happen when it is up.

Comment: You have to put into the #close click event And you also have to pass the event to the handler like : function(event) {
//your code
}